# Error running unit tests in intellij : Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "thread-count" must be declared for element type "test"

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, junit, testng

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=52696:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/testng/lib/testng-rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/openjsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Users/mehparmar/Repos/mehparmar/abc-java-library-parent/abc-java-library/target/test-classes:/Users/mehparmar/Repos/mehparmar/abc-java-library-parent/abc-java-library/target/classes:/Users/mehparmar/Repos/mehparmar/abc-java-library-parent/abc-java-library-interfaces/target/classes:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.13.4/jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.13.4/jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.13.4/jackson-core-2.13.4.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/maven/maven-model/3.3.1/maven-model-3.3.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.ant/0.8.7/org.jacoco.ant-0.8.7.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.8.7/org.jacoco.core-0.8.7.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.8.7/org.jacoco.report-0.8.7.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.7/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.7.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.9.1/gson-2.9.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-report-parser/3.0.0-M6/surefire-report-parser-3.0.0-M6.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-logger-api/3.0.0-M6/surefire-logger-api-3.0.0-M6.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.3.4/maven-shared-utils-3.3.4.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.1.0/maven-reporting-api-3.1.0.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.11.1/doxia-sink-api-1.11.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.11.1/doxia-logging-api-1.11.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.8/httpclient-4.5.8.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.11/httpcore-4.4.11.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.1/httpmime-4.3.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/main/jenkins-core/2.277.3/jenkins-core-2.277.3.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/main/remoting/4.6/remoting-4.6.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/main/cli/2.277.3/cli-2.277.3.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/version-number/1.7/version-number-1.7.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/crypto-util/1.5/crypto-util-1.5.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jvnet/hudson/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev-hudson-1/jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev-hudson-1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/google/inject/guice/4.0/guice-4.0.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/connectbot/jbcrypt/jbcrypt/1.0.0/jbcrypt-1.0.0.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jruby/ext/posix/jna-posix/1.0.3-jenkins-1/jna-posix-1.0.3-jenkins-1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/github/jnr/jnr-posix/3.1.4/jnr-posix-3.1.4.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/github/jnr/jnr-ffi/2.2.1/jnr-ffi-2.2.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/github/jnr/jffi/1.3.1/jffi-1.3.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/github/jnr/jffi/1.3.1/jffi-1.3.1-native.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.0/asm-analysis-9.0.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.0/asm-util-9.0.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/github/jnr/jnr-a64asm/1.0.0/jnr-a64asm-1.0.0.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/github/jnr/jnr-x86asm/1.0.2/jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/github/jnr/jnr-constants/0.10.1/jnr-constants-0.10.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/stapler/stapler-groovy/1.262.1/stapler-groovy-1.262.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/stapler/stapler-jelly/1.262.1/stapler-jelly-1.262.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/commons-jelly/1.1-jenkins-20120928/commons-jelly-1.1-jenkins-20120928.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.3/dom4j-2.1.3.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/windows-package-checker/1.2/windows-package-checker-1.2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/stapler/stapler-adjunct-timeline/1.5/stapler-adjunct-timeline-1.5.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/stapler/stapler-adjunct-codemirror/1.3/stapler-adjunct-codemirror-1.3.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/io/jenkins/stapler/jenkins-stapler-support/1.1/jenkins-stapler-support-1.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/infradna/tool/bridge-method-annotation/1.13/bridge-method-annotation-1.13.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/stapler/json-lib/2.4-jenkins-2/json-lib-2.4-jenkins-2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/net/sf/ezmorph/ezmorph/1.0.6/ezmorph-1.0.6.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1-jenkins-2/commons-httpclient-3.1-jenkins-2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/args4j/args4j/2.33/args4j-2.33.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/bytecode-compatibility-transformer/2.0-beta-2/bytecode-compatibility-transformer-2.0-beta-2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/asm6/6.2/asm6-6.2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/constant-pool-scanner/1.2/constant-pool-scanner-1.2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/task-reactor/1.5/task-reactor-1.5.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.15/xstream-1.4.15.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.4c/xpp3-1.1.4c.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.19/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jfree/jcommon/1.0.23/jcommon-1.0.23.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.10.9/ant-1.10.9.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.10.9/ant-launcher-1.10.9.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/commons-digester/commons-digester/2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.19/commons-compress-1.19.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/sun/mail/jakarta.mail/1.6.5/jakarta.mail-1.6.5.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.1/jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/commons-jelly/commons-jelly-tags-fmt/1.0/commons-jelly-tags-fmt-1.0.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/commons-jelly/commons-jelly-tags-xml/1.1/commons-jelly-tags-xml-1.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jvnet/hudson/commons-jelly-tags-define/1.0.1-hudson-20071021/commons-jelly-tags-define-1.0.1-hudson-20071021.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/commons-jexl/1.1-jenkins-20111212/commons-jexl-1.1-jenkins-20111212.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/5.4.4/spring-security-web-5.4.4.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.4.4/spring-security-core-5.4.4.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.12.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/jline/jline/2.12/jline-2.12.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/1.2.7/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.7.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.30/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.30/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/sun/xml/txw2/txw2/20110809/txw2-20110809.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/relaxngDatatype/relaxngDatatype/20020414/relaxngDatatype-20020414.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jvnet/winp/winp/1.28/winp-1.28.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/memory-monitor/1.9/memory-monitor-1.9.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/codehaus/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.9/wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/akuma/1.10/akuma-1.10.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/libpam4j/1.11/libpam4j-1.11.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/sun/solaris/embedded_su4j/1.1/embedded_su4j-1.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/net/java/sezpoz/sezpoz/1.13/sezpoz-1.13.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/jinterop/j-interop/2.0.8-kohsuke-1/j-interop-2.0.8-kohsuke-1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/jinterop/j-interopdeps/2.0.8-kohsuke-1/j-interopdeps-2.0.8-kohsuke-1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/samba/jcifs/jcifs/1.2.19/jcifs-1.2.19.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jvnet/robust-http-client/robust-http-client/1.2/robust-http-client-1.2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jenkins-ci/symbol-annotation/1.1/symbol-annotation-1.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/kohsuke/access-modifier-annotation/1.16/access-modifier-annotation-1.16.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1-jenkins-2/commons-fileupload-1.3.1-jenkins-2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.1/guava-11.0.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ppl/test/qi/client/testframework-testng-client/1.0.24/testframework-testng-client-1.0.24.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ppl/test/qi/client/abc-testng-listener/1.0.24/abc-testng-listener-1.0.24.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ppl/test/qi/client/testng-listener-commons/1.0.24/testng-listener-commons-1.0.24.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ebay/aero/cal-client-impl/3.3.0/cal-client-impl-3.3.0.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.10/commons-configuration-1.10.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ebay/aero/aero-kernel/2.2.4/aero-kernel-2.2.4.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ebayinc/platform/raptor/metadata-runtime-local/2.2.1/metadata-runtime-local-2.2.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ebayinc/platform/raptor/metadata-api/2.2.1/metadata-api-2.2.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ebay/aero/aero-jmx/2.2.4/aero-jmx-2.2.4.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ebayinc/platform/config/config-client/4.2.1/config-client-4.2.1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ppl/usf/commons/1.1.2/commons-1.1.2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ebay/kernel/uKernelCore/9.2.2/uKernelCore-9.2.2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ppl/test/qi/client/abc-testng-listener-jaws-plugin/1.0.24/abc-testng-listener-jaws-plugin-1.0.24.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/3.10.0.Final/resteasy-jaxrs-3.10.0.Final.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jboss/spec/javax/ws/rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec/2.0.1.Final/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jboss/spec/javax/xml/bind/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.3/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jboss/spec/javax/annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec/2.0.1.Final/jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/github/stephenc/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0-1/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/ppl/test/qi/client/abc-testng-listener-mako-teststeps/1.0.24/abc-testng-listener-mako-teststeps-1.0.24.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/testng/testng/6.14.3/testng-6.14.3.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/com/beust/jcommander/1.72/jcommander-1.72.jar:/Users/mehparmar/.m2/raptor2/org/apache-extras/beanshell/bsh/2.0b6/bsh-2.0b6.jar com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket52695 @w@/private/var/folders/6n/kcp2mfmx0s9_lqw9y30yqq500000gq/T/idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp /private/var/folders/6n/kcp2mfmx0s9_lqw9y30yqq500000gq/T/idea_testng.tmp
org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 57; Attribute "thread-count" must be declared for element type "test".
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:327)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 57; Attribute "thread-count" must be declared for element type "test".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:152)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:233)
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:295)
    ... 3 more

Process finished with exit code 255
```

The test I am able to run manually using mvn clean install but not working through intellij. So definetely sure that this is an intellij issue. Invalidated cache and resync dependencies but still nothing worked. The xml file in picture is the unit test I am running.This is a temporary file in cache folder of intellij. What is wrong with it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="abc-java-library-parent">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.xyz.test.qi.library.TestDataProcessorImplTest">
        <methods>
          <include name="testMultiModuleE2EflowTestJunit"/>
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- com.xyz.test.qi.library.TestDataProcessorImplTest -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- abc-java-library-parent -->
</suite> <!-- Default Suite -->
```

Comment: try moving `thread-count` to `suite` tag

Comment: @deadshot I am not creating this xml. This is automatically created by intellij.